# ValueError Expected 2 Got 1 Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, stdin

I'm trying to read the following data into my program.

```
Distance (m) Mass (kg) 
0.0865 0.1
0.1015 0.15
0.4416 0.9
0.4304 0.95
0.437 1.0
```

I'm using the following code, which is straight out of the book.

```
def getData(fileName):
    dataFile = open(fileName, 'r') 
    distances = []
    masses = []
    discardHeader = dataFile.readline() 
    for line in dataFile:
        d, m = line.split(' ')
        distances.append(float(d))
        masses.append(float(m))
    dataFile.close()
    return (masses, distances)
```

The code consistently returns:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I've looked at other ValueError entries, here and on the web, that pertain to reading space-separated data into a program, but have yet to find one with a substantially similar problem.

I conjecture that the problem is the line `d, m = line.split(' ')`. I'm not sure what this is called (compound assignment? tuple assignment?), why it's not working (I've never tried it this way before, but it seems reasonable), or how to make it work. If anyone who has approached reading in a file this way could shed some light on the situation, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's no space in one of the lines in your file.

Comment: Try adding `print(line)` at the start of your loop to see which line it is failing on.

Comment: I suspect the "last" line ends with a linefeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called *unpacking*. When you have an iterable (list, tuple, or anything that supports indexing), a syntax like `x, y = point` gets the `point[0], point[1]` elements and assigns them to `x, y` respectively. However, if there is no `point[0]` or `point[1]` it will throw an exception

That is what happens in your case, most probably because some line in your file is missing a space between the two values, so `line.split(' ')` returns just one thing

Comment: Thanks for addressing the question of what that type of syntax is and what it does! The authors assume it is self-evident.

Answer (score 2):

You probably ran into a blank `new line` at the end of the file, that gave only one item list (`['']`) when being splitted. (Also, splitting by blank space doesn't require parameter, it's the default).

---

```
if len(line.split()) < 2: continue
```

at the beginning of the loop should solve it.